# How could I get directory name from the full path without using dirname()?

Tags: c

dirname() is really terrible, because it modifies the argument so that it need another ugly copy of the original string. So no dirname(), please.

Is there any function like that but which is able to use safely?

Comment: I'm using C. I'll remove the C++ tag then.

Comment: you can use    `getcwd()`(http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html )

Comment: @EsmaeelE - that returns the current working directory. This is entirely a different task to extracting the folder name from a full path. (Which, for instance, may exist on a network share or the like - a location in which there is no notion of the current working directory) ;)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: To fix the horrible workaround when I was stupid (two years ago);

```
std::string_view getDirName(std::string_view filePath) {
    return filePath.substr(0, filePath.rfind('/'));
}
```

Comment: "*it need another ugly copy of the original string*" doesn't the solution you show do as well?

Comment: As you explicitly mention to use C: Those casts to `fullpath` and `malloc()` are pretty useless. `index` should be be `size_t`. `sizeof (char)`  equals 1 by definition.

Comment: The checks against failure of `strdup` and `malloc` are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C99 or C11 do not know about directories, which is a notion provided by some operating system API (or some external library above it).

On Linux, [dirname(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dirname.3.html) man page shows examples calling [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html):

```
       char *dirc, *basec, *bname, *dname;
       char *path = "/etc/passwd";

       dirc = strdup(path);
       basec = strdup(path);
       dname = dirname(dirc);
       bname = basename(basec);
       printf("dirname=%s, basename=%s\n", dname, bname);
```

<sup>(of course you should `free` both `dirc` and `basec`, and the code above don't check for failure of `strdup`)</sup>

You might also want the canonical directory of a path, using [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html). For example, you would code:

```
char* filepath = something();
char* canpath = realpath(filepath, NULL);
if (!canpath) { perror("realpath"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
// so canpath is malloc-ed
char *candir = dirname(canpath); // would modify the string in canpath
/// use candir here, e.g.
printf("canonical directory for %s is %s\n", filepath, candir);
free (canpath);
```

BTW, glib offers [g_path_get_dirname](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-path-get-dirname) (whose result should be `free`d).

Answer (score 0):

The freebsd man page of `dirname(3)` says that *The dirname() function returns a pointer to internal storage space allocated on the first call that will be overwritten by subsequent calls.*  so check your documentation.  Anyway, you can get a safe call if your implementation modifies directly the input string with:

```
char *aux = dirname(strdup(the_path));
...
free(aux);
```